# ogmios startup issue

Tags: cardano-node

I have a testnet running and now want to attach ogmios server to the cardano node socket, so as to probe the blocks. The ogmios agent is compiled separately and now when i want to attach it to the socket using:

ogmios 
--host 0.0.0.0
--node-config $BASE_CONFIG 
--node-socket $SOCKET

I am getting the following output:

```
config is ./../../src/tconfig/testnet-config.json
socket is ./../state-node-shelly-testnet/node.socket
{"severity":"Warning","timestamp":"2021-10-29T20:47:04.921466233Z","thread":"4","message":{"tag":"OgmiosMetrics","metrics":{"recommendation":"run with '+RTS -T'"}},"version":"v4.0.0-59-gc02eeb5c"}
{"severity":"Info","timestamp":"2021-10-29T20:47:04.922465452Z","thread":"4","message":{"tag":"OgmiosNetwork","networkParameters":{"networkMagic":1097911063,"systemStart":"2019-07-24T20:20:16Z","slotsPerEpoch":432000}},"version":"v4.0.0-59-gc02eeb5c"}
{"severity":"Notice","timestamp":"2021-10-29T20:47:04.926252351Z","thread":"6","message":{"tag":"OgmiosHealth","healthCheck":{"tag":"HealthShutdown","reason":"AsyncCancelled"}},"version":"v4.0.0-59-gc02eeb5c"}
ogmios: Network.Socket.bind: resource busy (Address already in use)
```

I understand that cardano-node is using the socket and hence that error comes. But how then should ogmios work ?

Answer (score 1):

ok. Later found that even if one runs the ogmios within a docker it actually attaches to the parent cardano-node process socket ! Strange. So only when i killed the docker process, then the host socket was free !